# Matching certain combinations of letters while avoiding false-positives

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to match U.S. English phonemes, which are one- or two-characters that represent a sound (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717239(v=vs.85).aspx).

Each phoneme must be separated by a space.  For the purposes of this question (unless you want to follow the link and use the actual phonemes), let's say that the phoneme set consists of the following:  "a", "aa", "ae", "bb", "cc".  There might be only one phoneme in the string, or there might be any number of any combination of them (space-delimited).  How can I match "a" or "aa" without matching "aaa"?

The following is not quite correct:

```
    If Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, "^([(a)(aa)(ae)(bb)(cc)]( )?)+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then
        MsgBox("valid")
    Else
        MsgBox("invalid")
    End If

    'Also doesn't work: If Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, "^([(a{1,2})(ae)(b{2})(c{2})]( )?)+$",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors:

```
\b(?:a|aa|ae|bb|cc)\b
```

Here is how to iterate through the matches.

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("\b(?:a|aa|ae|bb|cc)\b", RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim MatchResults As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
While MatchResults.Success
    ' matched text: MatchResults.Value
    ' match start: MatchResults.Index
    ' match length: MatchResults.Length
    MatchResults = MatchResults.NextMatch()
End While
```

Comment: That would surprise be greatly, you must have a typo. See [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/20).

Comment: Ah. I was at work, and only have access to VBScript there, and so was transcoding to that.  Something got lost in translation.  Thanks for the help!